# App Rejected from appStore, crashing on iOS 8.1.1

Tags: ios, ios8.1

I am new to the iOS development. 
I have developed an app using xcode 6.1.1. Every thing is working fine at my end, but when i submit the app to appStore, it gets rejected with the reason that app is crashing when we login with your test account.

I have tested it multiple times but its working fine. Anyone could help me with this. please.

This is the crash log apple sent me.

```
{"app_name":"Twiddle","app_version":"1.0","bundleID":"com.kashif.IddleApp","adam_id":942404426,"os_version":"iPhone OS 8.1.1 (12B435)","slice_uuid":"d3417619-43f1-3cf2-bbd0-258b0b834ec9","share_with_app_devs":false,"build_version":"1.3","is_first_party":false,"bug_type":"109","name":"Twiddle"}
Incident Identifier: 58556AE6-8830-4225-8CB2-28C0491B9F86
CrashReporter Key:   2f2f63ecce6bbcb980083b4fce70ee29ff474e5a
Hardware Model:      xxx
Process:             Twiddle [939]
Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/A81FF7B6-7106-4896-AC38-FCC09F4655C2/Twiddle.app/Twiddle
Identifier:          com.kashif.IddleApp
Version:             1.3 (1.0)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2014-12-18 23:01:56.857 -0800
Launch Time:         2014-12-18 23:00:43.083 -0800
OS Version:          iOS 8.1.1 (12B435)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
(0x182c5a59c 0x1937d00e4 0x182b451f8 0x1000d1ac0 0x187440d34 0x187429e48 0x1874406d0 0x18744035c 0x1874398b0 0x18740cfa8 0x1876abf58 0x18740b510 0x182c129ec 0x182c11c90 0x182c0fd40 0x182b3d0a4 0x18bcb35a4 0x1874723c0 0x1000feaec 0x193e3ea08)

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000193f57270 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000193ff5224 pthread_kill + 108
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000193eceb14 abort + 108
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000192fb5414 abort_message + 112
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000192fd4b88 default_terminate_handler() + 300
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001937d03bc _objc_terminate() + 124
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000192fd1bb0 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 12
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000192fd1738 __cxa_rethrow + 140
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001937d0290 objc_exception_rethrow + 40
9   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182b3d150 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 568
10  GraphicsServices                0x000000018bcb35a0 GSEventRunModal + 164
11  UIKit                           0x00000001874723bc UIApplicationMain + 1484
12  Twiddle                         0x00000001000feae8 0x1000c8000 + 223976
13  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000193e3ea04 start + 0

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000193f3cc94 kevent64 + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000193e2497c _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 272
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000193e173b0 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 48

Thread 2 name:  WebThread
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000193f3ce7c mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000193f3ccf4 mach_msg + 68
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182c11ecc __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182c0fe20 __CFRunLoopRun + 936
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182b3d0a0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 392
5   WebCore                         0x0000000190980854 RunWebThread(void*) + 464
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000193ff3e7c _pthread_body + 160
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000193ff3dd8 _pthread_start + 156
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000193ff0fac thread_start + 0

Thread 3 name:  JavaScriptCore::BlockFree
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000193f57078 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000193ff2fe0 _pthread_cond_wait + 620
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x0000000192f64cac std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 52
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001840c95f8 JSC::BlockAllocator::blockFreeingThreadMain() + 228
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001840c4b7c WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 20
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000193ff3e7c _pthread_body + 160
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000193ff3dd8 _pthread_start + 156
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000193ff0fac thread_start + 0

Thread 4 name:  JavaScriptCore::Marking
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000193f57078 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000193ff2fe0 _pthread_cond_wait + 620
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x0000000192f64cac std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 52
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001843728b8 JSC::GCThread::waitForNextPhase() + 152
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018437295c JSC::GCThread::gcThreadMain() + 88
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001840c4b7c WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 20
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000193ff3e7c _pthread_body + 160
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000193ff3dd8 _pthread_start + 156
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000193ff0fac thread_start + 0

Thread 5 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000193f3ce7c mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000193f3ccf4 mach_msg + 68
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182c11ecc __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182c0fe20 __CFRunLoopRun + 936
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182b3d0a0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 392
5   CFNetwork                       0x00000001826424e4 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 436
6   Foundation                      0x0000000183b2dc08 __NSThread__main__ + 1068
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000193ff3e7c _pthread_body + 160
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000193ff3dd8 _pthread_start + 156
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000193ff0fac thread_start + 0

Thread 6 name:  WebCore: CFNetwork Loader
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000193f3ce7c mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000193f3ccf4 mach_msg + 68
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182c11ecc __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182c0fe20 __CFRunLoopRun + 936
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182b3d0a0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 392
5   WebCore                         0x00000001909b4670 WebCore::runLoaderThread(void*) + 284
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001840c4b7c WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 20
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000193ff3e7c _pthread_body + 160
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000193ff3dd8 _pthread_start + 156
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000193ff0fac thread_start + 0

Thread 7 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000193f57498 __select + 8
1   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182c178c4 __CFSocketManager + 656
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000193ff3e7c _pthread_body + 160
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000193ff3dd8 _pthread_start + 156
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000193ff0fac thread_start + 0

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000193f57c78 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000193ff1390 _pthread_wqthread + 988
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000193ff0fa4 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 9 name:  Dispatch queue: NSOperationQueue 0x17403ac20 :: NSOperation 0x1740ec100
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000193f57570 __semwait_signal + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000193e7992c nanosleep + 212
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000193ee3394 sleep + 44
3   Twiddle                         0x0000000100176ab8 0x1000c8000 + 715448
4   Foundation                      0x0000000183a54618 -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 632
5   Foundation                      0x0000000183b16268 __NSOQSchedule_f + 224
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000193e15368 _dispatch_client_callout + 12
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000193e1f4bc _dispatch_queue_drain + 1212
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000193e18470 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 128
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000193e21220 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 660
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000193e22758 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 104
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000193ff12e0 _pthread_wqthread + 812
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000193ff0fa4 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000193f57c78 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000193ff1390 _pthread_wqthread + 988
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000193ff0fa4 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000193f57c78 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000193ff1390 _pthread_wqthread + 988
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000193ff0fa4 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x00000001700f1437
    x4: 0x0000000192fd5dfd   x5: 0x000000016fd37410   x6: 0x000000000000006e   x7: 0x0000000000000f80
    x8: 0x0000000008000000   x9: 0x0000000004000000  x10: 0x0000000000000200  x11: 0x0000000000000000
   x12: 0x0000000000000000  x13: 0x0000000000000000  x14: 0x0000000000000002  x15: 0x0000000000000000
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x0000000000000000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x0000000197b3b310  x21: 0x0000000197b23ce8  x22: 0x00000001741432f0  x23: 0x0000000194452c80
   x24: 0x0000000000000001  x25: 0x00000001741432e0  x26: 0x0000000197b220a8  x27: 0x0000000000000001
   x28: 0x0000000000000000  fp: 0x000000016fd37370   lr: 0x0000000193ff5228
    sp: 0x000000016fd37350   pc: 0x0000000193f57270 cpsr: 0x00000000

Binary Images:
0x1000c8000 - 0x10028bfff Twiddle arm64  <d341761943f13cf2bbd0258b0b834ec9> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/A81FF7B6-7106-4896-AC38-FCC09F4655C2/Twiddle.app/Twiddle
0x1200f0000 - 0x120117fff dyld arm64  <36eff49275c23d2d815e48af33eea471> /usr/lib/dyld
0x18126c000 - 0x181366fff RawCamera arm64  <6bbc4b9acb833146b6474984ffb64519> /System/Library/CoreServices/RawCamera.bundle/RawCamera
0x181384000 - 0x18141bfff AGXGLDriver arm64  <588a1155fa4131eb8bf4d6e61d7fa98b> /System/Library/Extensions/AGXGLDriver.bundle/AGXGLDriver
0x181434000 - 0x1815c7fff AVFoundation arm64  <c9cd60a62cfb3e77be72db6cd3062a09> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation
0x1815c8000 - 0x18162cfff libAVFAudio.dylib arm64  <017d90360b443ae788ef31cfd73d17f6> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/libAVFAudio.dylib
0x181670000 - 0x181670fff Accelerate arm64  <e9ba7838f51634a7b59ed392be50e86f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x181674000 - 0x181686fff libCGInterfaces.dylib arm64  <1c5263fd8837312180cf40c3dbd52b2b> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/Libraries/libCGInterfaces.dylib
0x181688000 - 0x1818a7fff vImage arm64  <da44067fc79931c7aef1b7e88bf82a83> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x1818a8000 - 0x18194ffff libBLAS.dylib arm64  <e5276e7784ef34a4baca480264978ea0> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x181950000 - 0x181ccafff libLAPACK.dylib arm64  <165b05f9f75736d5ae8f5f39293bd6e7> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x181ccc000 - 0x181ce1fff libLinearAlgebra.dylib arm64  <5574ec3bd4e537e1b662d38a63aec58b> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLinearAlgebra.dylib
0x181ce4000 - 0x181d4cfff libvDSP.dylib arm64  <004f5668574139bc906c5fa4fdced3b1> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x181d50000 - 0x181d73fff libvMisc.dylib arm64  <5790e7ace143367ea6f2428852be384e> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x181d74000 - 0x181d74fff vecLib arm64  <211d7711a6e93fe8ae6d6b42585cad2d> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x181d78000 - 0x181da6fff Accounts arm64  <2508d336b9893176ad4e1bc67ff04188> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accounts.framework/Accounts
0x181da8000 - 0x181da8fff AdSupport arm64  <977faefc983d3d72ad5e531740e4130a> /System/Library/Frameworks/AdSupport.framework/AdSupport
0x181dac000 - 0x181e2efff AddressBook arm64  <09e2e24ef5e23fb8a62ae209466a64bd> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x181e30000 - 0x181f80fff AddressBookUI arm64  <e79239b432af33e783296d2a9841578e> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
0x181f84000 - 0x181f97fff AssetsLibrary arm64  <9bf190e7f6403dd4bf42085fd4046c7d> /System/Library/Frameworks/AssetsLibrary.framework/AssetsLibrary
0x182148000 - 0x182405fff AudioToolbox arm64  <f0b739a395993b808d66e85e1a6e9f18> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x1825a4000 - 0x1827affff CFNetwork arm64  <68adcebf440d30769bd2d67adc7932a2> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x1827b0000 - 0x182847fff CloudKit arm64  <8f226c83b2793a0db1eefa14d697c04b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CloudKit.framework/CloudKit
0x182848000 - 0x1828adfff CoreAudio arm64  <10aae62ba1c43dd29bc678fbf0f985ef> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x1828d0000 - 0x1828f1fff CoreBluetooth arm64  <9ccc8812db60356ebb123ca9ca36f958> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreBluetooth.framework/CoreBluetooth
0x1828f4000 - 0x182b32fff CoreData arm64  <33c0d795a45e35c9affed5cf9d83a8a1> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x182b34000 - 0x182e90fff CoreFoundation arm64  <83a9627362333366a8543e8c2d28166e> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x182e94000 - 0x182ff6fff CoreGraphics arm64  <783a6b9356ed3b41beba516b483affb1> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x18304c000 - 0x18304efff libCGXType.A.dylib arm64  <a23bc017fe0d3c2293a1391fe5ef658b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGXType.A.dylib
0x183050000 - 0x18305bfff libCMSBuiltin.A.dylib arm64  <f691d5f2368d3b7d8668c7cbf6044af7> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCMSBuiltin.A.dylib
0x183250000 - 0x18326efff libRIP.A.dylib arm64  <c7960ba6e4183d9cbb673b112b6ba300> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x183270000 - 0x18339dfff CoreImage arm64  <444c44b06f533bad9c1b030edd486b49> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
0x1833a0000 - 0x1833fdfff CoreLocation arm64  <d8470e5719473c82a5f089624a04a1e5> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x183438000 - 0x1834f6fff CoreMedia arm64  <af73ae8152763066a3fc18bcbcdecf94> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x1834f8000 - 0x1835c6fff CoreMotion arm64  <b4148dfdca2036e893becf42286d9e09> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion
0x1835c8000 - 0x183639fff CoreTelephony arm64  <f99cf601387938d3808c32e97a9a30cf> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x18363c000 - 0x18373efff CoreText arm64  <128434ae7dda35bf8830f1914999fe3a> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x183740000 - 0x18375cfff CoreVideo arm64  <402f868dbba63d59a3b2e738982b9d71> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x183760000 - 0x183884fff EventKit arm64  <15cacaa609e33790a3bc644eb4d92191> /System/Library/Frameworks/EventKit.framework/EventKit
0x183888000 - 0x183a1efff EventKitUI arm64  <469c69733fe33d2c972a9263314b2f04> /System/Library/Frameworks/EventKitUI.framework/EventKitUI
0x183a38000 - 0x183c8cfff Foundation arm64  <fb0544132648377c8d2683d597a3583d> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x183cbc000 - 0x183ce5fff GSS arm64  <7b3a88cbb59d33088db0fae35c30b7da> /System/Library/Frameworks/GSS.framework/GSS
0x183da4000 - 0x183e10fff IOKit arm64  <1cd3da5151d03be5a0ba0c30c19228ea> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x183e14000 - 0x1840aefff ImageIO arm64  <100a3b5e1ea13c89a9771cad8f9508b2> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x1840b0000 - 0x184550fff JavaScriptCore arm64  <8b0fade3317b38358fe56ac5ba61e2f3>
```

Comment: Cannot post the complete crash report. i hope you people wont mind

Comment: Did you test the app with credentials you provide to Apple while submission?

Comment: Yes i did. Its working absolutely fine.

Comment: on which device you did you check it?

Comment: iPhone 5 with iOS 8.1

Comment: Try to check it on a device with **arm64** architecture.

Comment: okay. let me do so. thanks for your help.

Comment: i tested it on iPhone6 Plus with iOS 8.1.1 but still there's no problem at my end

Comment: Problem Solved. 
Problem was that i was passing a null value to NSDictionary. 
Actually when you press Don't Allow button for permission alert of push notifications, none of these functions were called
-didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken
-didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError

and the variable was still not initialized.. --> NULL
so this was causing problem. I never checked it by dont allowing the permission.

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved. Problem was that i was passing a null value to NSDictionary. Actually when you press Don't Allow button for permission alert of push notifications, none of these functions were called

-didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken 
-didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError

and the variable was still not initialized.. --> NULL so this was causing problem. I never checked it by dont allowing the permission.

I am such a fool